# Is there any simple way to create background task in NativeScript/Angluar for IOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, angular, background, nativescript

I' am looking for solution to running custom process indefinetly in background, even if user quit from application. It would fetching data from the server and generate local notification. I' am working with Nativescript/Angular and I heard about `Workers` but as far as I know, they can't keep the process if the app is not in foreground. It would be greatful if the solution will be suitable for IOS and Android. Have you any ideas to do this? Thanks in advance for your involvement

Comment: There is no such capability on iOS. You can use background fetch to periodically load data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS can not run something on background continuously. It's the OS which decides when your background execution can run. Refer [BackgroundExecution docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/BackgroundExecution) for more info and samples.

On Android you are free to run it continuously at least until the user blocks it on his choice, sample implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services).